# ¿Cómo escribir desde un archivo en Flask?

Tags: html, python, flask

Buenos días, estoy tratando de escribir en un archivo con Flask pero aún no he podido Desde un archivo normal de `Python` si consigo la lectura y escritura, pero no he podido aún adaptarlo al formulario, no tengo idea de como hacerlo y navegando por la web no encontré una forma clara. Si alguien pudiera ayudarme estaría muy agradecido.

Este es mi código:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

def get_info():
    with open('interfaces.txt', 'r+') as f:
        for line in f:
            found_address = line.find('address')
            if found_address != -1:
                address = line[found_address+len('address:'):]
                print ('Address: '), address
            found_network = line.find('network')
            if found_network != -1:
               network = line[found_network+len('network:'):]
               print ('Network: '), network
            found_netmask = line.find('netmask')
            if found_netmask != -1:
               netmask = line[found_netmask+len('netmask:'):]
               print ('Netmask: '), netmask 
            found_broadcast = line.find('broadcast')
            if found_broadcast != -1:
               broadcast = line[found_broadcast+len('broadcast:'):]
               print ('Broadcast: '), broadcast
    return address

@app.route('/')
def showPage():
    addresses = get_info()
    return render_template('test.html', addresses=addresses)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
<form method="post" name="test">
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <label class="col-sm-3 col-sm-3 control-label">F1:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ addresses }}">
    </div>
    <button> Save </button>
```

Basicamente estoy consiguiendo la lectura, y correctamente me obtiene los valores y los muestra en su correspondiente input, ahora el problema surge al momento de querer guardar cambios y que sobrescriba en el archivo plano también.

Este es mi HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" name="test">

                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 col-sm-3 control-label">F1:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ addresses }}">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 col-sm-3 control-label"> F2:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ network }}">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 col-sm-3 control-label">F3:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ netmask }}">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 col-sm-3 control-label">F4:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ broadcast }}">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 col-sm-3 control-label">F4:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ filedata }}">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" name="Guardar" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick=" this.form.action ='/test' " title="Guardar"><i class="fa fa-save"></i>  Guardar</button>
</html>
```

¿Alguna solución? ¿Alguien podría ayudarme?

Comment: segun veo tu código... en la funcion `get_info` solo estas retornando la variable `address` por lo que si no entra en el if de address arrojaria un error o podria retornar Vacio (None),  y por otro lado, no veo que estes guardando algun archivo, en todo caso, cual archivo quisieras guardar???

Comment: @GermanAlzateMartinez Gracias por tu tiempo, lo que me regresa la variable es lo que muestra en los input en el HTML. Lo que quiero es que al modificar el input y le de a guardar esos valores cambien tanto en el formulario como en el .txt. No encuentro una manera para dar con eso.

Comment: Hola Álvaro, estaría bien ver también el contenido de interfaces.txt, si es posible, para tener toda la información completa y poder simular la app más facilmente. Saludos.

Comment: El fichero lo abres usando un *context manager*. En el momento que sales del mismo se cierra el acceso al fichero. Según estás haciendo, en el formulario debería haber un botón que llame a una nuea función que se encargue de guardar los nuevos datos, es decir, debería abrir nuevamente el fichero y guardar los datos en ese momento.

Comment: Donde es `'interfaces.txt'` relativamente de "main.py"?

Comment: Si dices que quieres guardar los cambios en un archivo de texto plano, no veo en todo el código donde haces escritura en es e archivo. Por cierto, nunca haces `f.close()` al archivo, además evidentemente la lectura es peligrosa ya `w+` limpia todo el archivo para escribir, una buena lectura se hace con `r+`. Saludos.